# Problem with floating of AnalogRead

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, battery, system-design, network

For a university Lab course i have to realize a UPS unit with a internal LiPo battery . The unit uses as battery charger a buck converter

I have only a problem with the battery charger (buck converter). Few weeks before i verify the code and it works without problem. Now i can notice that the analog value that i read are floating too much and this represents a problem for the Constant Current (CC) and Constant Voltage (CV) phases of the battery charge process.

I found that this problem happens when plug arduino  after i have started the PC, while it doesn't happen when i plug the USB cable of arduino and then start the PC. It seems to be a problem with the ground of arduino.

the circuit scheme is the following one:
[image]

and what i obtain is that:

[image]

as you can see i have a strange increase of all the voltage that i read with the analog pin of arduino. The code is correct since before this week it works well, but if necessary i will upload it.

the 10Ohm resistor is placed in the buck converter only to measure the chargin current that i calculate as:

charging_current=(analogRead(A1)-analogRead(A2))*5.00/1023.00

The battery must be charged at constant current equal to 50mA until the battery voltage became equal to 4.10V, after that value the battery must be charged at constant voltage equal to 4.20V until the charging current became smaller than 10/5mA.

Notice that i try also to make more acquisition for each voltage: i made 8 measurement and then i calculate the average value, but the result doesn't change.

Comment: Please add information about which measurement are floating and what the actual and expected ranges are.

Comment: The measurement that are flosting are the voltsge that i masured on the network, on the battery and on the resistor... So all the vale that i read from analogo PIN of Arduino...the network voltage should be around 6V while the resistor voltage and the battery voltage should grow up while the battery charges... The start from 3.40V and the should reach about 4.20V

Comment: I can't make head nor tail of that fritzy thing. Please provide a *proper* schematic that we can follow.

Comment: I try to give you more detail information about the problem and i post a schematic of the battery charger. The other componente are ok so i can focus on the buck converter

Comment: I would expect some fluctuation, based one where in the PWM cycle you are doing the measurement. That is, based on whether the mosfet is turned on or not.

Comment: there are same fluctuation but sometime they are very smaller, like 40mV other time they are very big, like 100/150mV. On other thing that i note right now while i was testing the circuit, is that if i move the usb cable the voltage read frome the 3 pin (A0,A1 e A2) changes a lot, like 1V....this is due to the fact that the cable that i'm using isn't a cable of good quality?

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to measure waveforms? Then do this, please. And you might like to use an output of your Aduino to mark the times you read the analog inputs. Trace these, too.

Comment: i don't have an oscilloscope....

Comment: put caps in parallel with the voltage divider resistors, start around 100u. Also, you can expect a few levels of noise on a built-in ADC no matter what. Use an external ADC for more accurate + precise readings.